# Can't stop the global command using subcommand :substitute (:s) with the check flag (c)

Tags: command-line, gvim, substitute, global-command

I'm trying to use the global command `:g` with `:substitute` to find and replace some string and also with check.

So the command like:

```
g/\d/s/.*//gc
```

but the check behavior is not same as in `:s`

I can't quit or stop with <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd>
Whatever I enter <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd> message will still shows `replace with (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?` until the end of match result.

Is there any way to do the same behivor with check as `:s` in `:g` ?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may  be you could accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `:g` command enter in a loop that `q`, <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't break

For your case I would do:

```
:%s/.*\d.*//gc
```

Remark: <kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> break the loop of Vim and Neovim (for both `nvim` and `nvim-qt`) but not for gVim.

Comment: Is there any way to break in `:g` using `:s` with `c`?

Comment: I don't think so :-/

Comment: Given the other answer, that question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

`:help :g` can definitely be aborted with `<C-c>`, as per the documentation:

> Use "CTRL-C" to interrupt the command.

The `/g`, `/c`, etc. flags are features of `:help :s`. `:g` doesn't have that and there is no *easy* way I know of to somehow simulate it.

Furthermore, `/c` (for "confirm", not "check") only works for the *current* substitution. When you do:

```
:g/\d/s/.*//gc
```

you are actually doing as many substitutions as there are lines with digits in them. Because there is no delay or visible feedback when leaving one substitution and entering another, it all *feels* like a single substitution, but it really is not. This means that `q` effectively "quits" the *current* substitution, only to put you into the *next* one, which feels a bit like `q` doesn't work, while it actually works as intended.

---EDIT---

Maybe this will help…

Given the following sample:

```
aaapat1bbbpat2 pat2bbb;
aaapat1bbbpat2 pat2bbb;
aaapat1bbbpat2 pat2bbb;
aaapat1bbbpat2 pat2bbb;
aaapat1bbbpat2 pat2bbb;
```

the following command

```
:g/pat1/s/pat2/rep/gc
```

will create *6* nested loops:

```
l1
    pat2
    pat2
l2
    pat2
    pat2
l3
    pat2
    pat2
l4
    pat2
    pat2
l5
    pat2
    pat2
```

- An *outer loop* with five iterations, one for each matching lines.
- Five *inner loops*, one for each iteration of the outer loop, each with two iterations.

In other words, you have:

- *one* "`:g` loop", that you can interrupt with `<c-c>` at any point,
- and *five* "`:s` loops", that you can quit *individually* with `q`,

not one single "`:s` loop" as you seemed to expect.

`q` being solely handled by `:s`, pressing it at any point will quit the current *inner loop* as expected and, since there is nothing left to do in the current iteration of the outer loop, move to the next one and enter its corresponding inner loop.

If your outer loop has *five* iterations, then it executes *five* separate `:s` commands and you must press `q` *five* times to quit each of them in sequence. The other relevant commands in that `/c` prompt work the same so…

- If you want the current substitution to be the last, then you will need to press `l` once, and then press `q` as many times as there are iterations left in the outer loop.
- If you want to accept the current substitution and the following ones, then you will need to press `a` once for the current substitution and again for the first substitution of each remaining inner loop.

In short:

- the `/c` prompt only works in `:s`,
- `q` or `a` or `l` in that prompt only have effect for the current `:s`,
- `:g` doesn't have anything even remotely similar,
- `:g` can be interrupted by `<C-c>`,
- a single `:%s` seems more appropriate for your use case anyway.

Comment: In my tests `<C-c>` has the same effect as `q` in the example mentionned. Do you experience something else?

Comment: I experience the expected behavior: the loop is `Interrupted`.

Comment: I have the same behavior but not for gVim on Windows.